# Spring boot, storing CRUD operations in abstract service

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

I have two JPA entites like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {...}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {...}
```

And services like

```
@Service
public class AServiceImpl implements AService {

    @Autowired
    private ARepository aRepository;
    
    public void create() {...}
    public void update(long id) {...}
    public void doA() {...}

}

@Service
public class BServiceImpl implements BService {

    @Autowired
    private BRepository bRepository;
    
    public void create() {...}
    public void update(long id) {...}
    public void doB() {...}

}
```

So, in methods `create` and `update` I have code what differs only by repository. I would like to store crud methods in some other, basic service, but do not really understand how could I manage repository inheritance.
Any help, please.

Comment: use Generics, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMP: This code is compiling, I havent tested it.**

I think you can use Genarics over here.

```
public class RepositoryService <R extends JpaRepository<T, Long>, T> {

  @Autowired R repository;

  public void insert(T object) {
    repository.save(object);
  }

}
```

How to effectively use these reporitories, that details you can refer to this baeldung article - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire-generics

**Update: This is an alternate approach you can try out**

```
public abstract class RepositoryService <T>{

  abstract Class getRepositoryClass();

  Map<Class, GenericRepository> repositories;

  @Autowired
  List<GenericRepository> repositoriesList;

  @PostConstruct
  public void setupMap() {
    // Convert List into Map, with the class of Objest to be saved.
  }

  public void insert(T object) {
    repositories.get(object.getClass()).save(object);
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I didn't want store my repositories (second approach), but generics worked beautifully for me.